# Mario's Super Picross - Stage Mario 9-K

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, video-games, nonogram

I'm playing through [Mario's Super Picross](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario%27s_Super_Picross) currently and after nearly 200 puzzles this one finally has me stumped as to how it is intended to be solved. What is the next step to solving this?

[image: partially filled in puzzle]

Notes:

- This is a "Mario" stage so the game penalizes mistakes and doesn't provide a mechanism for forward-solving/backtracking. I have "solved" the puzzle by attempting to fill the rightmost column and using penalty/lack of penalty to gain information about the correct solution, but I'd like to get this with logic!
- I can write out the game mechanics in more detail if requested but I don't think they're super relevant beyond the above note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rightmost column

> the 6 must be at the top.

If it were are the bottom, row 17 (always included in the 6) would force the 7 in the next column to the bottom too, but it wouldn't fit because of the 1 on row 18 (also always included in the 6) forces  r18c19 to be empty.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's simpler and progresses the rest of the puzzle with more ease :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the 9th column (2,7,1):

> you've filled two cells there; the lower one could be from either the 1 or the 7, but the upper one *must* be from the 7. Extending downwards from that upper one, there's not enough space for it to be the top cell of the 7, so **the one above it must be filled too**.

Then in that row (4,9),

> you can blank out one more cell on the right.

Then in that column (8,3),

> the 8 must be *above* the newly-blanked cell and the 3 must be below, as there's not space for both of them together on either side.

That allows you to fill in quite a few cells in that column, which will then enable you to make more deductions in the relevant rows.

Comment: Ah, I love the smell of a fresh nonogram in the evening :-)

Comment: I knew I was missing something super obvious!